# Find difference between two values?

Tags: python

I have a random data set, and I was wondering if it is at all possible to find all sets of points where the difference between them is greater than some constant. It doesn't matter if the points aren't consecutive, as long as the difference between the corresponding value is greater than that constant.

Comment: we'd need an example of the data

Comment: Use nested loops that go through the data set and calculate the difference between the elements.

Comment: please, be more specific: add sample of input and desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and probably should) use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), no nested loops required.

E. g.: if we want to find elements from numbers between 10 and 15 (including 10 and 15) which difference is greater than 3:

```
from itertools import permutations

numbers = range(10, 16)
restriction = 3

filtered_numbers_pairs = []
for value, other_value in permutations(numbers, r=2):
    if value - other_value > restriction:
        filtered_numbers_pairs.append((value, other_value))

print(filtered_numbers_pairs)
```

gives us

```
[(14, 10), (15, 10), (15, 11)]
```

or if you need to store values indexes – just add [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
from itertools import permutations

numbers = range(10, 16)
restriction = 3

filtered_numbers_pairs = []
for (index, value), (other_index, other_value) in permutations(enumerate(numbers), r=2):
    if value - other_value > restriction:
        filtered_numbers_pairs.append((index, other_index))

print(filtered_numbers_pairs)
```

gives us

```
[(4, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for. I truly appreciate it

Comment: @alexanderson: you are welcome (you can also [vote on answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 3):

Python supports sets:

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> type(a)
<type 'set'>
>>> b = {2, 4, 5}
>>> a-b # Finds all items in a, but not in b.
set([1, 3])
>>> b-a # Finds all items in b, but not in a.
set([4, 5])
>>> (a-b).union(b-a) # Finds the union of both differences.
set([1, 3, 4, 5])
```

See `help(set)` for documentation.

To apply this to your question, however, will need an example of the data you have and the outcome you want.  Eg, some normalization may be required, or maybe you aren't dealing with sets afterall.

Comment: what you have done is called [`symmetric difference`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), and `set` have a [method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) for it: `a.symmetric_difference(b)` (but i don't know if it is what OP is looking for)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: Indeed, it seems that the operators have overloaded '-' to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry for wording the question in a wrong way by using the word "set". I was looking for a pair of number in a random data set that, if multiplied, would yield a constant value. I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: No worries - you've selected @azatibrakov's answer, which clarifies what you meant.  No harm done!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
It would be something like this:

```
sets = []
for item1 in dataset:
    for item2 in dataset:
        if abs(item1 - item2) > somevalue):
            sets.append((item1, item2))
```

You create a `sets` list, which is gonna hold the value-pairs which have a absolute difference bigger than `somevalue`. Then you append the sets containing the values of those items into `sets`.

EDIT: The list `sets` is a mutable object, if you want that to be immutable, this code won't work for you.

Comment: name `sets` is misleading, makes me think that it contains `set` objects

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: Ain't that a subtle hint? ;)

Comment: It does contain set objects, it is a list of sets

Comment: @gabrielbelini: Please see my answer - A set is a supported type.  You are using lists to *simulate* sets, but you aren't using the native set type there.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops

```
diff = []
for i, val1 in enumerate(dataset):
    for j, val2 in enumerate(dataset[i+1:]):
        if abs(val1 - val2) > some_constant:
            diff.append((i, j))
```

The inner loop uses a slice of the array so we don't add both `i, j` and `j, i` to the result.